# Holding int values in a list with a string, sorting by the int value

Tags: python-3.x, list

First of all here is the code I have so far for my small project.

```
# Problem: working out a percentage of minutes

# Inputs: percentage constant, empty list [activities], total activity time

PERCENTAGE = 100

activities = []

total_minutes = int(input('What was the total mobile phone usage (minutes) '))

# Loop: take users activity inputs
while sum(activities) < total_minutes:
    activity_name = input('What was the activity? ')
    activity_time = int(input('How many minutes on this activity? '))

    # Add the activity to the list
    activities = activities + [activity_name, activity_time]

print(activities)
```

'''Now, what I am aiming to do is have the activity name with the time spent on the activity in the list [activities]. I want to be able to retrieve either the activity name or time individually and to also "activities.sort()" by the integer value while obviously coinciding with the correct activity name.

Please make your answer as simple as possible (for someone in his early stage of university, second module)

Thanks in advance :)'''

Comment: for your list concatenation to work (keeping your activities in pairs) you need your lists to have the same size -> `activities = activities + [[activity_name, activity_time]]` or shorter `activities += [[activity_name, activity_time]]`

Comment: oops i forgot [Sorting HOW TO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sortinghowto) (official python tutorial on sorting)

Comment: Thanks for your help you have taught me a few little tricks there, I still don't get back my expected results but I have saved the code for future use in continuing to learn.